# FTP out of Azure App Service to folder on on premise server

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an API that runs in Azure App Service.

I have created a Subnet in Azure for my App Service, to be able to see the on premise server.  However, when I try to use an FTP path to the on premise server from within my app running in Azure App Service, it does not work.

Trying to navigate to the `\\172.28.2.10\\somefoler\\anotherfolder`, it gets mapped to the following drive on the machine my API in Azure is running on: `D:\\172.28.2.10\\somefoler\\anotherfolder`. It gets mapped to the D drive on the machine my API is hosted on.

How do I successfully FTP to a folder on a server that is not hosted in my Azure enviornment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need either:

1. A hybrid connection from your App Service blade panel:

[image]
[https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/using-azure-app-services-with-hybrid-connections/#:~:text=Hybrid%20Connections%20is%20both%20a%20service%20in%20Azure,enable%20an%20alternate%20capability%20to%20access%20your%20application](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/using-azure-app-services-with-hybrid-connections/#:%7E:text=Hybrid%20Connections%20is%20both%20a%20service%20in%20Azure,enable%20an%20alternate%20capability%20to%20access%20your%20application).

2. VPN gateway site to site or point to point to your on-premise resource.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/vpn-gateway/tutorial-site-to-site-portal

3. Expressroute

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/hybrid-networking/expressroute-vpn-failover